# Interfacing SystemC events and Qt events

Tags: qt, systemc

I am thinking about interfacing SystemC and Qt, with the goal of simulating a Cyber-Physical system. Is there already any framework around for mapping Qt's signals/slots to SystemC events? (say, entering a value in a box triggers a SystemC multiplexer, which selects an entry in a list, and that value is displayed as a number on an LCD display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is completely possible to interface SystemC events and Qt framework signals/slots together.
As per my current knowledge currently there are no readily available framework for this integration.

Here are a few pointer you can use for developing such framework:

- SystemC kernel has it's own/OS threading library depending on the configuration options provided while building it.
- So you will have to write wrapper modules which will keep the Qt framework and SystemC threads in sync depending on the GUI events.

**Note:** SystemC kernel is a co-operative multi-tasking based hardware simulator.